# NodeJS - How to resolve “Cannot find module 'ar-drone' ” error

Tags: node.js, ar.drone

I installed the following package over the command prompt:

```
npm install -g ar-drone
```

and then hit via Node.js

```
var arDrone = require('ar-drone');
```

and it gives me cannot find module 'ar-drone'

I thought when I install something with -g it will be installed globally?

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the module is downloaded in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` if you use ubuntu. Thats the global location for node_modules.

Also you can try to install in your local directory.

Comment: was in there, still doesn't work, no idea why, but I just wrote the code into a .js file and executed that

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had to transfer all code from index.js to repl.js. My repl.js looks like so and works.

```
let arDrone = exports;

exports.Client           = require('./lib/Client');
exports.UdpControl       = require('./lib/control/UdpControl');
exports.PngStream        = require('./lib/video/PngStream');
exports.UdpNavdataStream = require('./lib/navdata/UdpNavdataStream');

exports.createClient = function(options) {
  let client = new arDrone.Client(options);
  client.resume();
  return client;
};

exports.createUdpControl = function(options) {
  return new arDrone.UdpControl(options);
};

exports.createPngStream = function(options) {
  let stream = new arDrone.PngStream(options);
  stream.resume();
  return stream;
};

exports.createUdpNavdataStream = function(options) {
  let stream = new arDrone.UdpNavdataStream(options);
  stream.resume();
  return stream;
};
let client  = arDrone.createClient();
client.createRepl();
```